# Comparing 2 PDF in iFrames in web page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, comparison, bulma

Here's the project:

1. Have multiple PDF docs
2. Want to allow the user to display by choosing from a list of documents, any 2 of them side by side for comparison
3. Need to scroll and to be able to change the document in window from some sort of list.

I've done it with iFrame except for the being able to choose part (see code below).  So after hours of searching this site, I can't quite find an answer on how to choose a file and then send it to an iFrame.

Not set on iFrames, just what I thought of so far.  I'm open to suggestions!  (Also, note I'm using Bulma for CSS framework)

Thank you!

```
`enter code here`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
        <title>Illustrations of Masonry</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">
        <script defer src="js/fontawesome-all.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
<section class="hero is-link">
          <div class="hero-body">
            <p class="title">
              Illustrations of Masonry
            </p>
            <p class="subtitle">
             Compare Editions
            </p>
          </div>
</section>
        
<section>        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns is-center">
              <div class="column">
                <iframe src ="pdf/1772.pdf" width="100%" height="1000">
                <p>Your browser does not support iFrames.</p>
                </iframe>
            </div>
              <div class="column">
                <iframe src ="pdf/1781.pdf" width="100%" height="1000">
                <p>Your browser does not support iFrames.</p>
                </iframe>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</section>       
    
            
    </body>
</html>

UPDATE! Found a JS script that's close but I need help making it work across 2 iFrames. Sorry, huge noob here! ;-)  Feels like I'm close!


<section>        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns is-center">
              <div class="column">
                 <button id="btn1" >1772</button>
                <button id="btn2" >1775</button>
                <button id="btn3" >1781</button>
                <iframe id="frame1" src="http://www.tlhinteractive.com/preston/pdf/1772.pdf" width="100%" height="1000">
                  <p>Your browser does not support iFrames.</p>
                </iframe>
            </div>
                
              <div class="column">
                <button id="btn4" >1772</button>
                <button id="btn5" >1775</button>
                <button id="btn6" >1781</button>
                <iframe id="frame2" src="http://www.tlhinteractive.com/preston/pdf/1772.pdf" width="100%" height="1000">
                  <p>Your browser does not support iFrames.</p>
                </iframe>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</section>       
        
        
        <script>
            var frame = document.getElementById("frame1");
           var frame2 = document.getElementById("frame2")
        

var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
var btn4 = document.getElementById("btn4");
var btn5 = document.getElementById("btn5");
var btn6 = document.getElementById("btn6");

btn1.addEventListener("click",link1)
btn2.addEventListener("click",link2)
btn3.addEventListener("click",link3)
btn4.addEventListener("click",link1)
btn5.addEventListener("click",link2)
btn6.addEventListener("click",link3)
            
            
function link1(){
  frame.src="http://www.tlhinteractive.com/preston/pdf/1772.pdf"
}
function link2(){
  frame.src="http://www.tlhinteractive.com/preston/pdf/1775.pdf"
}
function link3(){
  frame.src="http://www.tlhinteractive.com/preston/pdf/1781.pdf"
}
            
function link1(){
  frame2.src="http://www.tlhinteractive.com/preston/pdf/1772.pdf"
}
function link2(){
  frame2.src="http://www.tlhinteractive.com/preston/pdf/1775.pdf"
}
function link3(){
  frame2.src="http://www.tlhinteractive.com/preston/pdf/1781.pdf"
}
        </script>
```

Comment: Update!  Found some JS that works on one iFrame at a time but can't figure out how to make it work across 2 iframes.  Sorry, huge noob! ;-)

Comment: Can you try something like this - https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-print-iframe-content-using-jqueryexample.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear I know what you are looking for but try the code below and see if that does what you want.  I did not use your pdfs so replace the .html pages with you pdf links.  All I did was take the code that you have and name the function link1-link6 instead of having two link1's, two link2's and two link3's.  OR what you can also do is add the code for frame2 in the link 1 function separated by a semi-colin.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
        <title>Illustrations of Masonry</title>
        
        <script defer src="js/fontawesome-all.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
<section>        
       <div class="container">
            <div class="columns is-center">
              <div class="column">
                 <button id="btn1" >1772</button>
                <button id="btn2" >1775</button>
                <button id="btn3" >1781</button>
                <iframe id="frame1" src="0101001.html" width="100%" height="1000">
                  <p>Your browser does not support iFrames.</p>
                </iframe>
            </div>
                
              <div class="column">
                <button id="btn4" >1772a</button>
                <button id="btn5" >1775b</button>
                <button id="btn6" >1781c</button>
                <iframe id="frame2" src="0101002.html" width="100%" height="1000">
                  <p>Your browser does not support iFrames.</p>
                </iframe> 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</section>       
    
            
    </body>
</html>

UPDATE! Found a JS script that's close but I need help making it work across 2 iFrames. Sorry, huge noob here! ;-)  Feels like I'm close!


    
        
        
        <script>
            var frame = document.getElementById("frame1");
           var frame2 = document.getElementById("frame2")
        

var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");
var btn4 = document.getElementById("btn4");
var btn5 = document.getElementById("btn5");
var btn6 = document.getElementById("btn6");

btn1.addEventListener("click",link1);
btn2.addEventListener("click",link2);
btn3.addEventListener("click",link3);
btn4.addEventListener("click",link4);
btn5.addEventListener("click",link5);
btn6.addEventListener("click",link6);
            
            
function link1(){
  frame.src="0101001.html";
}
function link2(){
  frame.src="0101002.html";
}
function link3(){
  frame.src="0101003.html";
}
            
function link4(){
  frame2.src="0101004.html";
}
function link5(){
  frame2.src="0101005.html";
}
function link6(){
  frame2.src="0101006.html";
}
        </script>
```

Comment: Jay: Thank you so much!  This works like a champ and does exactly what I need.  How would it look to add the frame2 to link1 function?  In any event, this is great, thank you!

Comment: Take this line and add it to the link1 function. frame2.src="0101004.html";  Make sure you end the lines with a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the tip!